# Mock and Test DynamoDB Table created by Amplify @model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I used @model annotation to create a table and a function that adds an entry in that table as a PostAuthentication Trigger to User pool. 
It works fine when I push it to AWS. But facing some issues in testing it locally.

MockData is there in amplify/mock-data/dynamodb/fake_us-fake-1.db

In the function/function_name/index.js

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { Logger } from '@dev.tools.thinkclear/common-util';

const options = {
  region: 'us-fake-1',
  endpoint: "<local_url>:62224/",
  accessKeyId: "fake",
  secretAccessKey: "fake"
};

AWS.config.update( {
  region: 'us-fake-1',
  endpoint: "<local_url>:62224/",
  accessKeyId: "fake",
  secretAccessKey: "fake"
});

const dynamoDBClientVar = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(options);
// Some Data params 
const data = await dynamoDBClient.put(params).promise();
```

local_url is the same url where ***amplify mock api*** is running . Changed the port to 62224 for dynamodb.

**amplify mock function function_name**

It's throwing Error: NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED error.

Checked this answer for reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925502/4578915

Comment: Have you watched this video? https://youtu.be/OxrHplxZ8BA   (Mocking and Testing Serverless APIs with AWS Amplify - AWS Online Tech Talks)

Answer (score 1):

I have configured it and it's working fine for me,

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Local
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'us-fake-1',
    endpoint: "http://localhost:62224/",
    accessKeyId: "fake",
    secretAccessKey: "fake"
});

// Live
// const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

Please with the above setting, if you have any query please dropped a message.