# Unable to query dynamodb GSI in lambda locally

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

So I added a lambda function category using the amplify CLI, in order to *query* data from the GSI(Global secondary Index) I created using the @key directive in the graphql schema. Whenever I try mocking the function locally using the `amplify mock function <functionName>` the callback function of the query keeps on returning null. The function can be seen below

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
});


 const params = {
  // ProjectionExpression: ["province", "gender", "updatedAt", "createdAt"],
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":provinceVal": "Sichuan",
  },
  IndexName: "RegistreesByProvince",
  KeyConditionExpression: "province = :provinceVal",
  TableName: process.env.API_PORTAL_SUBMISSIONSTABLE_NAME,
};

const calculateStatistics = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await db.query(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getStatistics: () => {
      return calculateStatistics();
    },
  },
};
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const typeHandler = resolvers[event.typeName];
  if (typeHandler) {
    const resolver = typeHandler[event.fieldName];
    if (resolver) {
      var result = await resolver(event);
      return result;
    }
  }
}; // };
```

I then tried to capture the whole event and logged it to the console as can be seen in the calculateStatistics function, which now showed me a bit more explicit error as follows.

```
     { UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1-fake' region.
    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:501:46)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at ClientRequest.error (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:339:22)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/work/web/portal/amplify/backend/function/calcStatistics/src/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:96:19)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
  message:
   'Inaccessible host: `dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com\'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1-fake\' region.',
  code: 'UnknownEndpoint',
  region: 'us-east-1-fake',
  hostname: 'dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  originalError:
   { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com:443
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
     message:
      'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com:443',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     code: 'NetworkingError',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com',
     host: 'dynamodb.us-east-1-fake.amazonaws.com',
     port: 443,
     region: 'us-east-1-fake',
     retryable: true,
     time: 2020-08-12T10:18:08.321Z },
  time: 2020-08-12T10:18:08.321Z }
Result:
null
Finished execution.
```

I then did more research and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883678/inaccessible-dynamodb-host-when-running-amplify-mock) thread about inaccessible-dynamodb-host-when-running-amplify-mock which I followed and tried implementing to but to no avail. Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

PS: It is worth mentioning that I was able to successfully query for this data through the Appsync console, which led me to strongly believe the problem lies in the function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research and asking around, I finally made sense of the answer that was provided to me on github that

> When running mock on a function which has access to a dynamodb
> table generated by API. It will populate the env with fake values. If
> you would like to mock your lambda function against your deployed
> dynamodb table you can edit the values in the sdk client so it can
> make the call accurately.

In summary, if you are running things locally, then you wouldn't have access to your backend variables which you might try mocking. I hope this helps someone. Thanks!