# How to drop and recreate local dynamodb/appsync/amplify database created by mock api?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Amplify to build a Web Application. I am using Appsync and DynamoDb and I've defined my GraphQL schema. Now, Amplify offers the ability to test local GraphQL endpoints by running "amplify mock api" from the command line. I did this and it successfully created some local GraphQL endpoints for me and I was able to insert some data and do some local queries. (When I ran "amplify mock api" the first time I got some messages on the console that my tables were created.)

I have since made quite significant changes to my GraphQL schema, including keys, sorting keys, etc. I don't think all of my changes successfully got applied to my local api and database tables. So I just basically want to completely delete my local "database" so that "amplify mock api" can regenerate a new local database for me based on my new schema. How do I do this? I don't know where this amplify local database resides or what underlying technology it uses. (Otherwise I would just connect directly to the database and drop all tables to force a recreation.) I have tried "amplify remove api" which removed the local endpoints. I even pushed this to AWS (I am in development mode currently, so I didn't mind destroying my AWS environment.) I then did "amplify add api" again from scratch and I typed out my schema again. But if I run "amplify mock api" then it doesn't recreate the tables. The endpoint starts up and if I perform a GraphQL query I get the data back that I originally added. Which means those tables persist.

How can I completely drop my local "mock" Amplify Appsync GraphQL endpoints and database to force a recreate? (I am using a Mac, if it's relevant).

Answer (score 14):

It ended up being very simple. Amplify creates the mock data in ./amplify/mock-data. So to delete the database and recreate it I just deleted this directory in my project. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883678/inaccessible-dynamodb-host-when-running-amplify-mock) question was helpful in working out how the mock API and database setup works.

Comment: Were you able to seed data when you mocked your api? Can't figure out how to 'start' with some info (users, etc.) when calling 'amplify mock api'